# Unexplainable white space when resizing the browser

Tags: html

I have a html/css problem.  I have a website which is made of a "wrapper" table in width: 100%.  In this website there is a "results" page, which shows a table with many different products and their columns of information.  Due to the fact that there are many columns, the table exceeds the size of the screen.  When I use the scroller to see that information, I see a big white space next to the "wrapper" table.
If anyone could explain to me how to get rid of that unwanted white space,
I had be very thanksfull.
ThankYou.

Comment: We need to see some code or a live example.

Answer (score 0):

we def need some code but perhaps you're not setting the parent objects to some height or width. White space on resizing is generally the cause of an object saving space for itself because in reality it could expand with more data.

you can try this 
html, body, form
        {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

or perhaps try fixing the widths and setting position to absolute.

Comment: Hey Everbody,
Thank you fo the replies. This happens in IE6.
I will get some code for you next week.
Thanks again.